# How to pass C# struct to C++

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I have a WP C++ Runtime Component that is to be consumed by a C# WP application.

In C++ Runtime Component, I have

```
public interface class ICallback
{
public:
    virtual void sendMail(Platform::String ^to, Platform::String ^subject, Platform::String ^body);
};
```

In C# Application, I have `CallbackImpl`, which implements `ICallback`:

```
public class CallbackImpl : Windows8Comp.ICallback
{
    public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String body)
    {
        //...
    }
```

And it works perfectly.

But now I need to pass something more complex than `String`: in C# I have

```
public class MyDesc
{
    public string m_bitmapName { get; set; }
    public string m_link { get; set; }
    public string m_event { get; set; }
}
```

and I have added:

```
public class CallbackImpl : Windows8Comp.IMyCSCallback
{
    private List<MyDesc> m_moreGamesDescs;
    public List<MyDesc> getMoreGamesDescs()
    {
        return m_moreGamesDescs;
    }
    // ...
}
```

How do I call it from C++?

```
public interface class ICallback
{
public:
    virtual <what ret val?> getMoreGamesDescs();    
};
```

I tried to create a "mirror" structure in C++ like this:

```
struct MyDescCPP
{
    Platform::String ^m_bitmapName;
    Platform::String ^m_link;
    Platform::String ^m_event;
}
```

but I don't understand what does C#'s `List` map to in C++.

Comment: It doesn't.  You need to use a WinRT interop type.  Expose the collection as `IReadOnlyList<T>` on the C# side, maps to `IVectorView<T>` on the C++ side.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks for your answer. The problem is now in `T` parameter. Compiler issues an error saying "... does not implement interface member ... because it does not have the matching return type ...". It seems that I cannot create mirror structure in C++ and I have to get it's declaration from C# somehow.

Comment: The T must be a type that itself exports across WinRT module boundaries.  If you declared it in the C# project then it must be sealed.  [Read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230301.aspx#DeclaringTypes).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
virtual List<MyDescCPP>^  getMoreGamesDescs();
```

there is no `^` (dash) next to `MyDescCPP` because unlike the `List<T>` which is a `ref` type, the `MyDescCPP` that you defined is a `struct` and that means it's a `value` type.

EDIT:

oh, and your `struct` must be `value class` or `value struct` because you want a `CLR` type there and not the native type:

```
value class MyDescCPP
{
    Platform::String ^m_bitmapName;
    Platform::String ^m_link;
    Platform::String ^m_event;
}
```

[Classes and Structs (C++ Component Extensions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w96b5h7.aspx)

Comment: It does not compile. Error string says "... because it does not have the matching return type ...". It seems that I cannot create mirror structure in C++ and I have to get it's declaration from C# somehow.